# Can CSS @import be set inside a class when using SCSS or SASS? Syncfusion example

Tags: css, sass, syncfusion

I have the following structure but can't get it to work.
The first CSS rules get always overwritten by the second import, no matter if the body class is light or dark.

Is there a way to do it purely with SCSS?

base.scss:

```
body.light {
  @import './light';
}

body.dark {
  @import './dark';
}
```

_light.scss:

```
@import '../../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material.css';
```

_dark.scss:

```
@import '../../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material-dark.css';
```

Comment: Depending on what criteria do the CSS files need to be imported? Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries in order to conditionally load CSS based on @media

Comment: See the example: class light imports the _light.scss file. class dark imports the _dark.scss file.

Comment: ok, so depending on whether your body element has the light class, you want to use the css from material.css and if it changes to the dark class you want to use the css from material-dark.css instead. AFAIK the imported rules do not become part of the selector. Meaning body.light is not a condition for the import. Of course you could always load the CSS with javascript whenever the class attribute of the body element changes.

Comment: Yes, the question is if imports can be encapsulated somehow. But apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

Greetings from Syncfusion.

We have checked this and we would let you know that we have already logged a feature request for this support that we can track using the below feedback portal.

Feedback: https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/8141/provide-latest-sass-version-support-with-ej2-components

We expect that it will be available with our Volume 3, 2020 release and we let you know the details for dynamically changing theme using SCSS. Until then, we request you to use the below method to change the theme dynamically.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10868/dynamic-theme-change

Please get back to us if you need any further assistance on this.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of those threads. In fact I participated in them. I used a simpler method without the Ajax package for now.
 `const styleTag: any = document.getElementById('theme');
styleTag.href =/styles/material-${colorScheme}.css`; But the solution is not great because you need both - material and material-dark - themes in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion Components are capable of dynamically generating theme file in compile time as in other third party components. But, we are not able to dynamically generate the themes in runtime as requested in the first query of this thread. We request you to use the methods
suggested in the below KB link for dynamic theme changing in the application.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10868/dynamic-theme-change